# ASP.net textbox with range textmode keeps resetting it's value

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

Hi i am busy creating a asp.net project that needs to get three values from the user. I am using a textbox with a range textmode to get these values and the first time the user moves the slider it works perfectly but after that the user can.t adjust any of the textboxes anymore.

I tried using a slider extender but this does not seem to work and only a textbox shows.

my html code to create the textboxes and labels showing the value

```
body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
            <p>
                Quantum 1 Length:&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtVal1" runat="server" TextMode="Range" min="1" Max="8" OnTextChanged="txtVal1_TextChanged1" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:Label ID="lblVal1" runat="server" Text="/////"></asp:Label>

            </p>

            <p>
                Quantum 2 Length:&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtVal2" runat="server" TextMode="Range" min="1" Max="8" OnTextChanged="txtVal2_TextChanged1" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:Label ID="lblVal2" runat="server" Text="/////"></asp:Label>
            </p>
            <p>
                Quantum 3 Length:&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtVal3" runat="server" TextMode="Range" min="1" Max="8" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txtVal3_TextChanged1"></asp:TextBox>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:Label ID="lblVal3" runat="server" Text="/////"></asp:Label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Height="24px" OnClick="btnNext_Click" style="margin-left: 0px" Text="Next" Width="150px" />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <script type="text/javascript" __designer:mapid="129">

               function NextPage() {
                                    window.open('Execution.aspx', 'Execution');
                                 }
</script>
                <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text="Invalid input; Please ensure that Quantum 1 &lt;= Quantum 2 &lt;= Quantum 3" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
            </p>
</form>
 </body>
```

My C# code used to control the boxes and change their values

```
 public partial class Quantums : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            txtVal1.Text = HttpContext.Current.Session["Q1"].ToString();
        }
        catch { }

        try
        {
            txtVal2.Text = HttpContext.Current.Session["Q2"].ToString();
        }
        catch { }

        try
        {
            txtVal3.Text = HttpContext.Current.Session["Q3"].ToString();
        }
        catch { }

        lblVal1.Text = txtVal1.Text;
        lblVal2.Text = txtVal2.Text;
        lblVal3.Text = txtVal3.Text;

        //UpdatePanel1.Triggers.Add(new AsyncPostBackTrigger() { ControlID = "btnNext" });
    }


protected void txtVal1_TextChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["Q1"] = txtVal1.Text;
    }
```

And then the same code for textbox 2 and 3. Any suggestions on why the textboxes vaklue keeps resetting and autopostback is enabled on all three buttons.

Comment: Just to be sure, you have methods 'txtVal2_TextChanged1' and 'txtVal3_TextChanged1', which set the correct session variable to the correct textbox value, right?

Comment: Yes i do have those methods in as well

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed you were missing `if(Page.IsPostBack()) return;`. Your problem is that every time you change your textbox, the 'Page_Load' event is enacted, then the respective event handler (see [page life cycle](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8911c4/page-life-cycle-with-examples-in-Asp-Net/)). So you were setting the text to the sessions, then setting the sessions to the text, effectively doing nothing.

You actually don't need anything for this page in the Page_load method, at least for now. Try the following:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void txtVal1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["Q1"] = txtVal1.Text;
        lblVal1.Text = txtVal1.Text;
    }

    protected void txtVal2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["Q2"] = txtVal2.Text;
        lblVal2.Text = txtVal2.Text;
    }

    protected void txtVal3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["Q3"] = txtVal3.Text;
        lblVal3.Text = txtVal2.Text;
    }
```

You can then access the user input values using the respective session values. For example:

```
    protected void Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> answers = new List<string>();
        answers.Add(Session["Q1"].ToString());
        answers.Add(Session["Q2"].ToString());
        answers.Add(Session["Q3"].ToString());

        // Do stuff with answers
    }
```